# UI Acceleo Launcher Project doesn't work

Tags: eclipse, plugins, acceleo, metamodel

I've followed this simple tutorial wiki.eclipse.org/Acceleo/Getting_Started my aim is creating an UI launcher...
However when I finish and a click on 'Acceleo Model to Text'>'generate' the folder 'src-gen' remains empty!!

On Error Log View this error is prompted:

```
java.io.IOException: '/elt/codegeneration/ecore2dataspace/files/generate.emtl' not found
at org.eclipse.acceleo.engine.service.AbstractAcceleoGenerator.initialize(AbstractAcceleoGenerator.java:409)
at elt.codegeneration.ecore2dataspace.files.Generate.<init>(Generate.java:90)
at elt.codegeneration.ecore2dataspace.ui.common.GenerateAll.doGenerate(GenerateAll.java:91)
at elt.codegeneration.ecore2dataspace.ui.popupMenus.AcceleoGenerateEcore2dataspaceAction$1.run(AcceleoGenerateEcore2dataspaceAction.java:76)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
```

It doesn't found the file generate.emtl although it is actually present in the jar file.

The strange thing is that when I try to start the plup-in in a separate Eclipse application (By Maniferst.mf) everything works!!!

I've Acceleo - Text generation from models Version: 3.1.0.
Eclipse Platform Version: 3.7.0

Thanks

Comment: If you managed to get over this would you please provide an answer? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The UI plugin generated needs to be deployed in another Eclipse instance to be used, it cannot be used in the current Eclipse instance. You can try it by launching the generator in a new Eclipse instance (Run As... Eclipse Application). You can build both plugins and export them to be [easily installed](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-1S2nyfQ7yMc/TfT_y_NUr2I/AAAAAAAAAak/xliU8VYZmx4/s800/Update%252520Site.png) for your end users.

You can find [an example](https://github.com/ObeoNetwork/UML-Java-Generation) of an Acceleo generator and its UI plugin with a maven based build on github.

Disclaimer: I am the leader of Acceleo

Answer (score 0):

I got also the same error of "generate.emtl" not found, which is the case since the emtl file is not in the right place in the jar (and i don't know why). The solution is to manually copy the file from "bin" folder, and the generation works.